# Why does shell_exec create more than 1 process?

Tags: php, python, shell-exec

I have this code:

```
Shell_exec( 'sudo python /etc/MACT/temp_alarm.py ' . $channel1 . ' temp' .  "> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &" );
```

It is triggered via the isset from php.  When I look at the process on the RPi, I can see two processes running.  Any thoughts on why?

Thank you.

Comment: What are the two processes? Where is this code executing?

Comment: Is this run from a form or button or something? Perhaps the button has been pushed several times?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a whole series of programs executed in response to that PHP command:

- A copy of /bin/sh to interpret the command line.
- A copy of sudo invoked by the above /bin/sh
- A copy of /bin/sh to interpret the sudo command line
- A copy of python invoked by the above /bin/sh
- Any programs invoked by temp_alarm.py during its execution.

Comment: here is the processes... I understand your comments.  What I do not want is multiple processes of the temp_alarm.py running as it sends emails.  Thank you.

grep --color=auto temp_alarm
/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/idle /etc/MACT/temp_alarm.py
sudo python /etc/MACT/temp_alarm.py
python /etc/MACT/temp_alarm.py
/bin/sh -c sudo python /etc/MACT/temp_alarm.py
sudo python /etc/MACT/temp_alarm.py
python /etc/MACT/temp_alarm.py

Comment: @metzz71 Can you put that in your question as a text block so we can see multiple lines?

Comment: grep --color=auto temp_alarm /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/idle /etc/MACT/temp_alarm.py 
sudo python /etc/MACT/temp_alarm.py 
python /etc/MACT/temp_alarm.py /bin/sh 
-c sudo python /etc/MACT/temp_alarm.py 
sudo python /etc/MACT/temp_alarm.py python /etc/MACT/temp_alarm.py